# Excel found unreadable content in 

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

When I open an excel file (generated through VBA code), I get an error

`"Excel found unreadable content in <filename>. Do you want to recover the contents?"`

Upon clicking yes, I get a message

```
'Repairs were made to PivotTable report 'pvtName' on '[filename.xls]Tab'.'
```

The pivot table in question is generated by the VBA code. Is there a way to figure out what repairs are being done on the pivot table, so that I can make the necessary changes in the code before the file is generated?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by making sure the file extension was .xlsm and the FileFormat 52 (Macro Enabled Workbook).

However, users with Excel 2003 won't be able to view the pivot table properly.

If someone has a better workaround, please let me know.